# The application works fully in console but not by clicking on the jar

Tags: java, scala, jvm, manifest

I have created an application with scala and it works from the console by using `java -jar application.jar`, but when I double click on my application, the application doesn't work fully.

This is a gif that I've take which show exactly the problem:

> [http://i.imgur.com/uitgSky.mp4](https://i.imgur.com/uitgSky.mp4)
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQRb6biSGf0

My manifest:

[image]

How to solve this problem? This is because I use scala?
I don't think it's really hard to fix because java -jar app.jar work great so...
Maybe it's the firewall which blocks the response from the server ? (I use the serversocket) ...

Comment: Salut. Assuming your systems can execute jars by double-clicking on them one problem might be the current working directory. Does your application work like this `cd \ ` and then `java -jar <absolute dir>\application.jar` ? Another hint might be the environment that is different e.g. the console doesn't have the same environment as the launcher when double-clicking. It is hard to tell with more information. You are saying the application is not fully working. What do you mean by "not fully"?

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? I've do that for instance : java -jar Desktop\Client.jar and it work in console ...

Comment: Do you have check the link above ? ;)

Comment: yeah just saw that is a video. so you mean the part where it is not echoing back to the console?

Comment: To the client, : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQRb6biSGf0

Comment: Jar files usually associate with `javaw` instead of `java`.  I'm not fully aware of the implications, but it could be a factor.  Try to right-click and run with java.  Also make sure its running with the correct java version.

Comment: I cant execute with  java instead of "java", http://i.imgur.com/o43WuFn.png

Comment: @KwizzyFR yes you can.  `Ouvrir avec` Then "more apps", and "look for another app on his PC" (Don't know the French options sorry) and find your java exe.

Comment: lol i've a scanner ... So it's the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after launch my app in console i've view a scanner in while and it's the cause of the problem.

Solved ;)